# How to use same bootstrap modal for 2 different submit buttons in django?

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have 2 buttons that basically submits form but I first need to confirm from user and used a modal for that

```
            <form action="{% url 'reset_pl' %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Clear Players
            </button>
            </form>

            <form action="{% url 'reset_all' %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Clear Teams
            </button>
            </form>
```

and a modal for it that I need to use with both of them but don't want to repeat code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="clear" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Clear" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-notify modal-danger modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <!--Content-->
    <div class="modal-content text-center">
        <!--Header-->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <p class="heading lead">Are you sure?</p>
        </div>
        <!--Footer-->
        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
           <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>

            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.Content-->
</div>
```

I am not sure how to dynamically change action of forms or let modal know where to actually submit form when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you don't need forms to do your resets. You can just use buttons with **custom classes** (e.g. reset-pl and reset-all) that trigger modal opening on click via its **data-target** attribute and at the same time pass appropriate url in **data-id** attribute of the button to the modal.

```
<button class="reset-pl" data-id="{% url 'reset_pl' %}" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#clear">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Clear Players
</button>

<button class="reset-all" data-id="{% url 'reset_all' %}" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#clear">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Clear Teams
</button>
```

Add appropriate **id** (e.g. reset-anchor) to your **Yes** anchor and leave **No** button as it is for modal closing.

```
<a id="reset-anchor" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Yes</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
```

Than in javascript just set the href attribute of **anchor** with reset-anchor id to appropriate url from **data-id** of the clicked button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".reset-pl").click(function () {
        $("#reset-anchor").attr("href", $(this).data("id"));
    });

    $(".reset-all").click(function () {
        $("#reset-anchor").attr("href", $(this).data("id"));
    });
</script>
```

In summary, when button is clicked modal is opened via data-target and at the same time url from data-id is set as href of **Yes** button via javascript. **Yes** button of course than triggers appropriate url when clicked.